# AG-grid scss/css token issue in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have an issue with a working with ag-grid-react. I keep getting an error that reads:

ERROR in ./node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.scss 8:73
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:73)

My webpack rule is:

```
   

     module.exports = {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
          },
        ],
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
            use: [
              // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
              "style-loader",
              // Translates CSS into CommonJS
              "css-loader",
              // Compiles Sass to CSS
              "sass-loader",
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                  limit: 8192,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      entry: {
        main: ['whatwg-fetch', 'core-js/stable', 'raf/polyfill']
      },
    
      resolve: {
        modules: [srcDirectory, 'node_modules'],
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.html', '.css','.scss']
      },
```

.tsx code is

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { Card } from '@jpmuitk/card';
    import { Panel } from '@jpmuitk/panel';
    import {AgGridReact, AgGridColumn} from 'ag-grid-react';
    
    import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.scss';
    import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.scss';
```